# NullReferenceException on ConcurrentBag.Add with threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was originally using a `List` for this but I changed to a `ConcurrentBag` after seeing that Lists where not "thread-safe".

The following is my code so far. When it runs, it will not add to the `ConcurrentBag`, I get a `NullReferenceException` -  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  and I am not sure what the problem is as I do not have much experience with threads.

```
static ConcurrentBag<String> urls;

// ...

static void buildThreads()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(buildTokens);
        thread.Start();
    }
}

static void buildTokens()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (numSockets < tokens)
        {
            getUrl();

            numSockets++;
            Console.WriteLine(numSockets + "/" + tokens);
        }
    }
}

static void getUrl()
{
    urls.Add("test");
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Try `static ConcurrentBag<string> urls = new ConcurrentBag<string>();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform this instantiating before accessing this object, it's contains a `null` reference right now:

```
static ConcurrentBag<string> urls = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
```

Comment: Oops, I knew it was going to be something little like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to "new" your concurrent bag (create an instance):

```
static ConcurrentBag<String> urls = new ConcurrentBag<String>()
```

If you are using Visual Studio to build and debug your code you should be able to place a break point on the line where you add to the bag and notice the value of the variable is "null"

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** Your `ConcurrentBag` variable `urls` is `null` as you have not initialised it properly.

**Solution:** You need to initialise your `ConcurrentBag` variable `urls` properly using `new` keyword.

Replace This:

```
static ConcurrentBag<String> urls;
```

With This:

```
static ConcurrentBag<String> urls = new ConcurrentBag<String>();
```